# Model Evaluate a fixed accuracy 0.5000

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I am training a CNN model using Keras on Google Colab for binary image classification, the problem is when I use the test dataset divided into 2 classes in the model evaluate the accuracy is fixed at 0.5000. When I use a test dataset without dividing the data into 2 classes this does not happen and I have an accuracy of 0.9167.

My code:

```
modelo.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(551, 1117, 3)))
modelo.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

modelo.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
modelo.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

modelo.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
modelo.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

modelo.add(Flatten())
modelo.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')) 
modelo.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

modelo.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = modelo.fit(traning_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks)
```

training result:

```
Epoch 1/10
13/13 [==============================] - 33s 3s/step - loss: 136.5746 - accuracy: 0.5300 - val_loss: 23.4487 - val_accuracy: 0.4068
Epoch 2/10
13/13 [==============================] - 27s 2s/step - loss: 5.3578 - accuracy: 0.4675 - val_loss: 0.7363 - val_accuracy: 0.4068
Epoch 3/10
13/13 [==============================] - 28s 2s/step - loss: 0.6870 - accuracy: 0.5925 - val_loss: 0.7120 - val_accuracy: 0.5932
Epoch 4/10
13/13 [==============================] - 18s 1s/step - loss: 0.5529 - accuracy: 0.7225 - val_loss: 0.8240 - val_accuracy: 0.3898
Epoch 5/10
13/13 [==============================] - 18s 1s/step - loss: 0.4633 - accuracy: 0.7750 - val_loss: 1.1202 - val_accuracy: 0.4322
Epoch 6/10
13/13 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.5213 - accuracy: 0.7675 - val_loss: 1.4779 - val_accuracy: 0.4407
Epoch 7/10
13/13 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.1730 - accuracy: 0.9550 - val_loss: 1.8047 - val_accuracy: 0.4492
Epoch 8/10
13/13 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.0887 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 2.4989 - val_accuracy: 0.4831
Epoch 9/10
13/13 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.0318 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 3.7380 - val_accuracy: 0.4407
Epoch 10/10
13/13 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.0070 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.7144 - val_accuracy: 0.4492
```

when testing dataset without class division I get:

```
test_loss, test_acc = modelo.evaluate(test_dataset)

1/1 [==============================] - 1s 577ms/step - loss: 0.6590 - accuracy: 0.9167
```

and when testing the test dataset with 2 classes:

```
2/2 [==============================] - 3s 653ms/step - loss: 1.2334 - accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: please share about training data and how are you labeling those.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the test dataset divided into 2 classes"?

Comment: are two classes like for example cat and dog. Which expects the network to know which of the classes a test image belongs to.

Comment: Yes we know that, what is not clear to me is what division in the test you are talking about, are these different test datasets?